# ggplot2 facet labels don't correspond to data

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I'm an R newbie and I'm probably missing something trivial, but here it goes:

I have a data frame `Data` with values like so:

```
         Voltage Current  lnI     VoltageRange
    1    0.474   0.001 -6.907755  Low Voltage
    2    0.883   0.002 -6.214608  Low Voltage
    3    1.280   0.005 -5.298317  Low Voltage
    .      .       .        .          .
    .      .       .        .          .
    .      .       .        .          .
    .      .       .        .          .
   13    2.210   0.247 -1.398367 High Voltage
```

Then I try to plot it with the following code:

```
ggplot(data = Data, mapping = aes(x = Data$lnI, y = Data$Voltage)) +
      geom_point() +
      stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
      facet_grid(~VoltageRange)
```

The output of which is:
[image]

As you can see, the facet labels are in the wrong place, what is labeled as High voltage corresponds to low voltage and vice versa.

How do I go about fixing this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: a better reproducible data frame would be nice. I don't know if this will make a difference. You can reduce your code a bit. no need to specify `mapping=`, and only use the column names and not the vectors, just call  `ggplot(Data, aes(x = lnI, y = Voltage)`

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, it only needed simplifying. No idea how it crept up... Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented. I think your ggplot call is 'too complicated'

```
require(read.so) #awesome package available on GitHub, by @alistaire47 
dat <- read_so() 
dat <- dat[c(1:3,8),] 

dat
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Voltage Current lnI       VoltageRange
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>     <chr>       
1 0.474   0.001   -6.907755 Low         
2 0.883   0.002   -6.214608 Low         
3 1.280   0.005   -5.298317 Low         
4 2.210   0.247   -1.398367 High 

ggplot(dat, aes(x = lnI, y = Voltage)) + # remove 'mapping', 
# and use only the object names, not the columns/ vectors
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  facet_grid(~VoltageRange)
```

works:
[image]

**edit**
If you want to re-arrange the facet, factorise the argument and change the order of the levels. You can do this in the data frame (which I would not recommend) or in the ggplot call directly. In order to do so, I find it good to create a character vector with the order of the levels, because you might need this one again.

```
facet_order <- c('Low', 'High') 
# note it's important that the levels are written exactly the same
ggplot(dat, aes(x = lnI, y = Voltage)) + 
      stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
      facet_grid(~factor(VoltageRange, levels = facet_order))
```

Comment: Thank you! By simplifying the code as you suggested, it works! Now I only have to google how to order the facets, but I've seen the question before somewhere...

Comment: the order is based on the alphabetical order or , if your column is a factor, on the underlying levels. I would in general recommend against having your data saved as factors , when you don’t really understand what factors are (they are messing up a lot , and often). I personally am defining a character vector with the correct order of the levels and then factorise the variable in the facet call directly using ‘factor(x, levels = my_character_vector)’

Comment: @GeorgeKampolis I have added this to my answer